Log geometric Frobenius morphism
Let $k$ be a perfect field of characteristic $p>0$ and let $R$ be a mixed characteristic discrete valuation ring with uniformiser $\pi$ and residue field $k=R/\pi$. Consider the affine $R$-scheme:
$$f:\mathcal{U}=\mathrm{Spec}\left( \frac{R[x,y]}{\langle xy - \pi \rangle} \right) \longrightarrow \mathrm{Spec}(R) $$
We endow $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ with the log structures given by the charts of monoids:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
{ \frac{R[x,y]}{\langle xy - \pi \rangle}} @<<< {\mathbb{N}^2} \\
@AAA & @AA\Delta A       \\
R @<<< \mathbb{N}\\
\end{CD}
where $(1,0)\mapsto x$, $(0,1) \mapsto y$ and $\Delta(1)=(1,1)$.
We use the superscripts $f^\dagger: \mathcal{U}^\dagger \to (\mathrm{Spec}(R))^{\dagger}$ to denote the corresponding morphism of log schemes. We endow the special fibres $f^\dagger_k: \mathcal{U}_k^\dagger \to (\mathrm{Spec}(k))^{\dagger}$ with the pullback log structures. The (relative) log Frobenius morphism $F_{\mathcal{U}_k^\dagger/k^\dagger}:\mathcal{U}_k^\dagger \to (\mathcal{U}_k^\dagger)^{(p)}$ is given by the usual relative Frobenius on schemes, and the log structure on $(\mathcal{U}_k^\dagger)^{(p)}$ is determined by the pushout of monoids:
\begin{CD}
S_p:=\mathbb{N}^2 \oplus_\mathbb{N} \mathbb{N} @<<< {\mathbb{N}^2} \\
@AAA & @AA\Delta A       \\
\mathbb{N} @<<\cdot p < \mathbb{N}\\
\end{CD}
It is then easy to see that $(\mathcal{U}_k^\dagger)^{(p)}= \mathcal{V}_k^\dagger$ where $\mathcal{V}=\mathrm{Spec}\left( \frac{R[u,v]}{\langle uv - \pi^p \rangle} \right)$ with chart given by $S_p$.
As $k$ is perfect, by taking the inverse of the power of $p$ map, one can define the geometric Frobenius morphism $F^{(-1)}:\mathcal{U}_k^{(1/p)}\rightarrow \mathcal{U}_k$ of $k$-schemes.
My question is, what should the log geometric Frobenius morphism be?
Intuitively, the log Frobenius twist $(\mathcal{U}_k^\dagger)^{(p)}$ 'remembers' that it sits in a non-regular scheme (a $\mu_p$-quotient singularity $\mathcal{U}/\mu_p$). Iterating the log Frobenius, we similarly obtain worse quotient singularities $\mathcal{U}/\mu_{p^n}$ and so it would seem that the geometric Frobenius should come from a 'less singular' scheme than $\mathcal{U}$ which is of course impossible. Perhaps this is reflected in the fact that the monoid homomorphism $\cdot p: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is not invertible.

The confusion seems to come from the fact that even though $k$ is perfect, the Frobenius $F_S$ on the base log scheme $S = {\rm Spec}(\mathbb{N}\xrightarrow{1\mapsto 0}k)$ is not an isomorphism, so it does not make sense to consider the pull-back of $\mathcal{U}_k$ along $F_S^{-1}$. Perhaps you should first take base change to the log perfection $S_\infty = {\rm Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[1/p]_+\to k)$.
Side remark: A possibly related issue is that the Frobenius does not lift to the log scheme $T = {\rm Spec}(\mathbb{N}\xrightarrow{1\mapsto p}R)$. This is an important point in the definition of the Frobenius action on Hyodo--Kato cohomology, in fact the reason why one considers the base $T' = {\rm Spec}(\mathbb{N}\xrightarrow{1\mapsto 0}R)$ instead. The famous Hyodo--Kato isomorphism is (basically) an isomorphism between the log crystalline cohomologies of a log smooth $X/S$ with respect to the two log PD thickenings $S\to T$, $S\to T'$, assuming $R = W(k)$, up to inverting $p$.

Dear Piotr, thank you for raising these two points. Indeed, my motivation comes from wanting to understand what the correct notion of Frobenius liftability from $k$ to $W_2(k)$ or even $W(k)$ is in the log geometry setting. Of course in the usual case it is essential that the Frobenius on $k$ lifts to $W(k)$ and one can further show that the Frobenius morphism always lifts on smooth affine varieties etc.

Related example: Let $$X = {\rm Spec}(W_2(k)[x,y]/(xy))\quad\text{and}\quad X' = {\rm Spec}(W_2(k)[x,y]/(xy - p))$$ (underlying schemes of reduction mod $p^2$ log smooth schemes over $T$ and $T'$). Then Frobenius lifts to $X$ (by $x\mapsto x^p$, $y\mapsto y^p$) but not to $X'$. To see the latter claim, suppose $F$ is a Frobenius lift, then $$p = F(p) = F(xy) = F(x)F(y) = x^p y^p + ph$$ for some $h$, contradiction. See the beginning of Section 3 of "Global Frobenius liftability II: surfaces and Fano threefolds" (Achinger, Witaszek, Zdanowicz, Ann. Sc. Norm. Super. Pisa Cl. Sci. (5) 2023).
